Get the wallpaper displayed by custom WallpaperServices
I implemented a wallpaperServices to replace the wallpaperServices in SystemUI
 
Now I can display images freely in MyWallpaperServices。
But,When other applications use WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).drawable, the obtained drawable is still the original WallpaperServices image。
 val wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this)
    val setWallpaperComponentMethod =
        WallpaperManager::class.java.getMethod(
            "setWallpaperComponent",
            ComponentName::class.java
        )

    val componentName = ComponentName(this, MyWallpaperServices::class.java)
    setWallpaperComponentMethod.invoke(wallpaperManager, componentName)

What do I need to do so that WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).drawable returns the image of MyWallpaperServices
I tried calling the WallpaperManager.setBitmap method in MyWallpaperServices
       private fun drawWallpaper(width: Int, height: Int) {
        val canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas()
        if (canvas != null) {
            val wallpaper = getOrLoadBitmap(wallpaperResources[currentWallpaperIndex], width, height)
            canvas.drawBitmap(wallpaper, 0f, 0f, null)
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
            WallpaperManager.getInstance(applicationContext).setBitmap(wallpaper)
        }
    }

This will cause MyWallpaperServices to become invalid and return to the original wallpaperServices
